# Examples of non-self-induced algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $A$ be a (possibly non-unital) algebra over $\mathbb C$.  We say that $A$ is *self-induced* if the product map $m:A \otimes_A A \rightarrow A$ is an isomorphism.  Here $A \otimes_A A$ is the balanced tensor product, the quotient of $A\otimes A$ by the linear span of elements of the form $ab\otimes c - a\otimes bc$.

This notion seems to have been introduced by Gronbaek in [Morita equivalence for self-induced Banach algebras](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0864.46026) and was further studied by Meyer in [Smooth and rough modules over self-induced algebras](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1252.18019).  If $A$ is unital, or more generally, has local, one-sided, units, then $A$ is self-induced.  I am interested in *non-trivial* examples of $A$ which are not self-induced.

> What is an example of $A$ which is not self-induced, but such that the product map is surjective, and such that the product is [non-degenerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_bilinear_form) (so for each non-zero $a\in A$ there are $b,c\in A$ with $ba\not=0, ac\not=0$).

---

I have tagged this functional analysis, as the notion seems to have arisen in the context of topological algebras (and so people working in this area might know examples).  But the question does not ask about the topological case.  I would be interested to know if this idea is studied in non-topological contexts under a different name?

[Asked on [Math.Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4419480/examples-of-non-self-induced-algebras) a few days ago, with no answers.]

**Partial leads:** Some "factorisation" results (relevant to $m$ being surjective in this algebraic situation) are considered by Dales, Feinstein, Pham in [Zbl 1471.46051](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1471.46051) (full-text [available here](http://www.research.lancs.ac.uk/portal/en/publications/factorization-in-commutative-banach-algebras(431c518b-0bbc-481e-b573-bc739cb81ecf).html)) which leads me to an old paper of Willis, [Zbl 0742.46032](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0742.46032).  These give very complicated examples of $A$ for which $m$ is surjective, but without there being local units, and so *maybe* they are not self-induced.  Unfortunately, I see no obvious way to check if they are self-induced.

That $m$ is onto means that $A$ is an *idempotent ring*.  Such rings, together with the non-degeneracy condition, and considered by Parvathi and Rao [Zbl 0682.16031](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0682.16031) and García and Simón  [Zbl 0747.16007](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0747.16007).  Unfortunately, these leads do not seem to lead to examples nor consideration of the "self-induced" idea.

Comment: You might look at http://www.claymath.org/library/Quillen/Working_papers/quillen%201996/1996-2.pdf and some papers on Morita equivalence for idempotent rings by Garcia and Simon.

Comment: My impression is M. Parvathi and A. Ramakrishna Rao, Morita equivalence for a larger class of rings, Publ.
Math. Debrecen 35 (1988), 65-71 considers Morita equivalence for idempotent nondegenerate rings so may have relevant info but I couldn't get a hold of the paper

Comment: Thanks!  Indeed, the zbmath review https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0682.16031 is rather hopeful!  Getting hold of the paper might be a challenge...

Comment: Quillen calls a module $M$ firm if $A\otimes M\to M$ is an isomorphism.  So you are asking if $A$ nondegenerate and idempotent is equivalent to $A$ being a firm $A$-module.

Comment: Apparently google reveals that some people call self-induced rings firm rings in keeping with Quillen.

Comment: Great.  Indeed, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra)#Properties_weaker_than_having_an_identity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this paper](http://real.mtak.hu/90053/1/laan_marki_reimaa.pdf) the authors consider the analogous question in the context of semigroups and I think basically the contracted semigroup algebra of their semigroup on page 5 works.  This argument should be ok over any base commutative ring with unit but to keep things easier I'll work over a field $K$.  If $S$ is a semigroup with zero, then the contracted semigroup algebra $K_0S$ has basis the nonzero elements of $S$ and we interpret a zero product in $S$ as zero in $K_0S$.

Let $S=\{a,b,c,d,0\}$ be the semigroup with zero with the following multiplication table:
$$ \begin{array}{c| c c c c c}
 &0 & a&  b &c& d\\\hline
0 & 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
a & 0& 0 &0& 0& a\\
b& 0& 0& 0& 0& b\\
c& 0& 0& a& 0& 0\\
d& 0& a& 0& c& d\end{array}$$

Put $A=K_0S$.  Note that $S^2=S$ since $d$ is a left identity for $a,c,d,0$ and a right identity for $a,b,d,0$.  Therefore, $A^2=A$, i.e., $m\colon A\otimes_A A\to A$ is surjective.

Next I claim that $A$ is non-degenerate.  Indeed, if $x=k_aa+k_bb+k_cc+k_dd$ with $xA=0$, then $0=xd = k_aa+k_bb+k_dd$, and so  $x=k_cc$.  But then $0=xb=k_ca$, hence $x=0$.  Similarly, if $Ax=0$, then $0=dx = k_aa+k_cc+k_dd$ and so $x=k_bb$.  But then $0=cx = k_ba$ and so $x=0$.

Observe that $A\otimes_{K} A$ has basis all pairs $(s,t)\in S\setminus \{0\}\times S\setminus \{0\}$ and that $A\otimes_A A$ is the quotient of $A\otimes_K A$ by the subspace $V$ spanned by all differences $st\otimes u-s\otimes tu$ with $s,t,u,st,tu\neq S\setminus \{0\}$. Note that $b\notin sS$ for $s\in S\setminus \{b\}$.  So a term in the spanning set for $V$ involving an element of the from $b\otimes c$ would have to look like $bt\otimes u-b\otimes tu$ with either $u=c$ or $tu=c$. If $tu\neq c$, then we would need $u=c$ and $bt=b$ to get $b\otimes c$.  But then $t=d$ and we get $b\otimes c-b\otimes c=0$.  If $tu=c$, then $t=d$, $u=c$.  But then we again get $b\otimes c-b\otimes c=0$.  Thus $b\otimes c$ does not appear in any term in the spanning set of $V$.  Since the $s\otimes t$ with $s,t\in S\setminus \{0\}$ form a basis for $A\otimes_K A$, we must have that $b\otimes c\notin V$.  Hence in $A\otimes_A A$, we must have $b\otimes c\neq 0$, but $m(b\otimes c)=bc=0$.  So $A$ is our example.

Nb.  It looks to me like $S$ is a $\ast$-semigroup with $b^*=c$, $c^*=b$ and all other elements self-adjoint, so you can choose $A$ to be a $\ast$-algebra over $\mathbb C$ if you like and the $\ell_1$-norm will make it a $\ast$-Banach algebra since it is finite dimensional.

Comment: Looks good to me. I ran a computer program that computed the generators of the subspace $V=\langle ab\otimes c - a\otimes bc\mid a,b,c\in A\rangle$ and according to these computations its dimension is 11  and $b\otimes c\notin V$.

Comment: @tj_, that sounds better than my argument. It seems then that this element generates the kernel

Comment: This is great, thanks so much.  As I am a masochist, I computed a basis for $V$ by hand, and also got 11 dimensions, and found directly that $b\otimes c\not\in V$.  To be honest, this was exactly the sort of example I was hoping for: finite-dimensional, and small enough to compute by hand.

Comment: People had been looking at firmness type ideas in semigroups for years to come up with some sort of Morita theory so I knew where to look.  I think there are general nonsense reasons that if the semigroup $S$ is not firm, but sometimes a semigroup can act faithfully on itself and still have a degenerate algebra so that had to be checked more carefully.